# Angular2 - Convert Blob to long base64

Tags: angular, image, blob

In a Angular2 project i want to take base64 and show it in a img. I take a string from a JSON and convert this to a Blob. Then i want to convert this Blob file to base64 string. This is the code.

```
   var blob = new Blob([response], {type : "image/jpg"}),
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
     console.log(reader.result);
    };
```

Response is

```
description: "URL [file:20201014_0822_05020362.jpg]"
file: "/20201014_0822_05020362.jpg"
filename: "20201014_0822_05020362.jpg"
inputStream: {}
open: false
readable: true
uri: "file:/20201014_0822_05020362.jpg"
url: "file:/20201014_0822_05020362.jpg"
```

This return

> data:image/jpg;base64,W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd

I suppose this is a short base64 string but i need to get long base64.

So, what is the correct way to convert blob file to long base64 and show it in img tag?

Comment: What is `meter.meterImage`? `W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd` is decoded: `[object Object]`

Comment: I update question with meter.meterImage (now response) content.

Comment: I don't think you need a blob at all. Just try `reader.readAsDataURL(result.uri);`

Comment: Return  Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.